# Keeping External Monitor Resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, external-monitor

Recently I got myself a new laptop which has two display adapters as of `lshw` report:

```
VGA compatible controller
                producto: GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
                fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
                versión: a1
                anchura: 64 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuración: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

And

```
VGA compatible controller
             producto: HD Graphics 630
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 2
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
             recursos: irq:137 memoria:dd000000-ddffffff memoria:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff
```

I suppose one is for normal use and the one is the 8GB *muscle* card.

During a heavy gaming session it fell off the table and the laptop's monitor was obliterated but I have a spare (external) monitor which I connected and configured, but which does not support the 120 Hz the card throws at it by default.

This can be solved, of course, on the configuration by turning it off.

The real problem occurs when I reboot: remember my card throws 120Hz at the HDMI by default? Well, suddenly my external monitor reports an unsupported resolution and I have to configure it all by hand.

I have used Linux for more than ten years but I still feel like a newbie most of the time, but I can think of at least two solutions:

- The first of course being directly editing the /etc/whatever and making my external display default to 60Hz and turning my laptop's monitor off.
- The second being a script calling XRANDR or something of the sort.

How should I fix this issue?